# Manual Laravel Validation using array index (not keys)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, validation

A newbie here in terms of Laravel validation - I've searched and checked the manual but can't seem to find an answer to this.  I'm using Laravel 8.0.

As  [per the Laravel manual](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#manually-creating-validators) I have created a manual validation to validate my array, it contains data similar to the below:

```
$row = array('John','Doe','john.doe@acme.com','Manager');
```

Because the array has no keys, I can't work out how to reference the array items using their index when creating the Validator, I've tried this:

```
$validatedRow = Validator::make($row, ['0' => 'required|max:2', '1' => 'required']);
$validatedRow = Validator::make($row, [0 => 'required|max:2', 1 => 'required']);
$validatedRow = Validator::make($row, [$row[0] => 'required|max:2', $row[0] => 'required']);
```

But no luck - does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I guess this cannot be possible. Laravel validator creates validation messages automatically based on some basic properties like :attribute (key names). So without giving the exact key name some of the features won't work and would make some bugs and errors. I recommend adding some required keys to the array(maybe using a method or service for this?) or store them with keys at first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Validator

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

Then Update your code

```
        $row = array('John','Doe','john.doe@acme.com','Manager');
        $rule = [
            '0' => 'required|string',
            '1' => 'required',
            '2' => 'required|email',
            '3' => 'required'
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($row, $rule);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()->all()], 422);
        }else{
            echo 'ok';
        }
```